# Ant Design Table + GraphQL

Tags: graphql, antd

What is the proper way to use a GraphQL Relay connection cursor with the Ant Design Table pagination?  It has really nice pagination, but the graphql server looks for a cursor and doens't need the "total" page number.   Any thoughts?

Comment: you can make 2 queries one for records the other one for count, does it sound wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I created a pagination component that replaced the actual `<Table>` component pagination.  Then I set `<Table pagination={false}>` and used my custom paginator to control the next and previous functionality without the numbered pages.

I am using graphql-ruby so I actually needed to enable [bidirectional pagination](https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/2079) instead of the classic docs from GraphQL.  It has since become a standard.